# Conditional fields: Hide/show fields based on the value of other fields

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Does Apostrophe 2 have conditional fields? I only found [this issue](https://github.com/apostrophecms-legacy/apostrophe-schemas/issues/9) at *apostrophecms-legacy* but no documentation for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` field type has an option called `showFields`, which you can use to conditionally show other fields based on the value of the select.

See https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-select-code

Comment: Awesome! Will the boolean and checkbox fields also have such showFields options in the future, or isn't this practical?

Comment: I'm not sure there's plans to implement it, but I imagine the team would accept a PR if you're interested in seeing it.

Comment: I'm gonna take a look at this. Thanks!